# Functional determinant: linking Series, Heat-Kernel and Zeta function

Tags: quantum-field-theory, action, partition-function, 1pi-effective-action, functional-determinants

I would like to express a functional determinant as a series of diagrams, using the zeta function renormalization applied to the heat-kernel method, but I don't know if it's possible. Let me explain:

I have a partition function $Z=\int \mathcal{D}H\,e^{-S-I-\Gamma^{(1)}}$, where $\Gamma^{(1)}$ has been evaluated by the zeta function applied to the heat kernel method, $S$ and $I$ are two actions and $H$ is a multiplet of fields. The action $I$ contains a quadratic term only, and so the integration along the field it depends on yields a determinant $\det(\Delta)$ of a Laplace-type operator. This very determinant, if evaluated with the same method as for obtaining $\Gamma^{(1)}$, will produce a term $-\Gamma^{(1)}$. And so the two $\Gamma^{(1)}$ will perfectly compensate. As you can see, it is not very interesting as it is presented until now.

I would like to express $\det(\Delta)$ as a series of diagrams, so that the complete series is $e^{+\Gamma^{(1)}}$. My goal is to suppress *progressively* the effective action $\Gamma^{(1)}$ from the path integral $Z$ such that each term of the series is finite, if possible.

I know that (for example) for $\Delta= \partial^2+A(x)$, where $A(x)$ is a field, we have :
\begin{equation}
\det(\Delta) = \det(\partial^2)\times \exp\left( \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n}\text{tr}\left[ (A(x)G(x-y))^n \right]\right).\tag{1}
\end{equation}
Which can be expanded into a sum of diagrams, more precisely each diagram is a single loop with sources attached to it.

The problem with this minimal example is that I am not sure if, with this method, $\det(\Delta)=e^{\Gamma^{(1)}}$. I imagine one has to use the zeta regularization of the heat kernel associated with $\partial^2$, but still, I can't tell if the previous equality holds. On the other side, the heat kernel method ($H.K.$) does give a series of terms:
\begin{align}
\det{}_{H.K.}(\Delta)=e^{\Gamma_\text{div}+\Gamma_\text{log}+\Gamma_\text{finite}}.\tag{2}
\end{align}
With $\Gamma_\text{div}$, $\Gamma_\text{log}$ and $\Gamma_\text{finite}$ three sums which are expressed in [this Scholarpedia article](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Heat_kernel_expansion_in_the_background_field_formalism#UV_divergences.2C_anomalies_and_local_expansion). Clearly, since $\Gamma_\text{div}$ is present, we have to regularize, but not all methods give the same result... And my intuition is that these sums will either collapse to one finite term or to $0$.

So my question is: does there exist a series $S_\Gamma$ of diagrams, like $(1)$, such that:
\begin{align}
e^{\Gamma^{(1)}} \stackrel{!}{=} S_\Gamma\tag{3}
\end{align}

---

What I mean by "zeta regularization applied to the heat kernel method" is the following formula:
\begin{align}
\zeta_\Delta(s) =  \frac{1}{\Gamma(s)} \int d^D x \sqrt{|g|}\lim_{y\rightarrow x} \int_0^{+\infty} dt\,t^{s-1}\langle x| e^{t\Delta} | y \rangle.\tag{A}
\end{align}