# Problem with different expressions of functional determinant

Tags: action, partition-function, qft-in-curved-spacetime, functional-determinants

This question is a follow-up of my [previous one](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/728322/functional-determinant-linking-series-heat-kernel-and-zeta-function), after having done some calculations. In this previous question I used a minimal example of my problem with $\det(\Delta) = \det(\partial^2+A(x))$, but the operator from which my problem arises is $D=-\square-A_\lambda \partial^\lambda+m^2$. My problem can be reduced to this:
\begin{equation}
\zeta'_D(0) \stackrel{?}{=}\zeta'_{-\square+m^2}(0)-\ln \det \left( 1+A_\lambda \partial^\lambda\frac{1}{\square-m^2} \right). \tag{1}
\end{equation}
So the question is, "Is this equality true?" In fact, whether I treat $\ln \det(\cdots)$ as just a series or with the Heat Kernel method, the result is the same:
\begin{align}
\ln \det \left(1+A_\lambda \partial^\lambda\frac{1}{\square-m^2} \right) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \int \prod_{k=1}^{n} d\mu_k \lim_{x_{n+1} \rightarrow x_1} \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n} \prod_{k=1}^{n} A_{\lambda_k}(x_k) \partial^{\lambda_k} G(x_k-x_{k+1}). \tag{2}
\end{align}
With $G$ the Green function of $\square-m^2$, and $d\mu_k = d^4x_k \sqrt{g(x_k)}$.

It is quite surprising because when expressing $D$ as a Laplace-type operator $-\nabla^2+m^2$ for some covariant derivative $\nabla$, the LHS of $(1)$ is expressed via the DeWitt coefficients of $D$, while the RHS doesn't have the same coefficients. Moreover, I don't see the correspondence between the Heat-Kernel expansion and the series of one-loop diagrams of the RHS of $(1)$...

I feel like saying that $1+1+1+1+\cdots = -1/2$.